# Posts.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I getting error while using below code

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import Post from '../post/Post'
import Share from '../share/Share'
import './feed.css'
import axios from 'axios'
export default function Feed() {
  const [Posts, setPosts]=useState([])
  useEffect(()=>{
    const fetchPost=async()=>{
      const res=await 
            axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/post/timeline/all/63cac03bc359a08187cb64b1`)
      setPosts(res.data)
      console.log("api data", res.data)
  
  }
   fetchPost();
   },[]);
  console.log("hook data",Posts)
  return (
   <div className='feed'>
     <div className="feedWrapper">
       <Share/>
       {Posts.map((p) => {
         <Post key={p._id} post={p} />
    })}
      </div>
  
    </div>
  )
  }
```

Data is successfully store in hook but map function getting an error:
Posts.map is not a function

Comment: what is data type of res.data ?

Comment: what is the result of ``console.log("api data", res.data)``?

Comment: The problem is here with the api response you are getting. Console.log the response & see what you are getting.

Comment: result of console.log("api data", res.data ) return api data successfully. its also save in hook but map function through an error

Comment: Your request code does not catch errors. So upon a failed req, Posts will be empty and map will not be available to it.

Comment: @MalikNaveed What I mean is that ``res.data`` may not be an array.